# Bootstrap Remote Modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a trouble loading a Modal from a remote page. The content is not being loaded into the modal but being loaded on top of the page. The modal doesn't even show up. Why is this not loading into the modal?

**Index Page**

```
 <script>
$('#modal').modal({
    keyboard: false,
    remote: "second.html",
    show: false
})
</script>

<a data-toggle="modal" href="second.html" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Load External Page</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Second Page**

```
<p>TEXT GOES HERE</p>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Have you included the Bootstrap CSS?

Comment: Yes, the Bootstrap CSS is included on the Index Page

Answer (score 1):

If you use bootstrap 3.1, the new one that came out just couple of days ago, they changed the remote-modal behaviour.
They did not changed the doc for it though.

As from 3.1 version the content of remote modal should **not** be placed in modal root but in .modal-content div

[Bug on github exlaining the undocumented new feature](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12494)

Comment: I am on Bootstrap Version 3.0.3.0